# How do I get rid of the white space at the top of my web page?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

How do I get rid of the white space at the top of my page?

I have tried css resets, removing <p> tags, changing `<body>`, `<html>`, and `<div>` margins and nothing seems to work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title><meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #container {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                width: 800px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            #inner-container {
                margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            }
            p {
                margin-top: 0px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body><div id="container"><div id="inner-container">
                    <p>Body Text</p>
            </div></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your whitespace is coming from the top margin of 10px on #inner-container. See this JSFiddle with the top margin changed to 0px: https://jsfiddle.net/rcz6ksft/.

```
#inner-container {
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: My guess is you meant for #inner-container to have padding to expand the black background instead, as well, instead of offset the whole element?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove margins for child elements as they will create the white gaps if they are close to the edge of the website. I have updated the margins to be padding instead., this will create the same effect however the element will span right to the edge of the page.

```css
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #container {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                width: 800px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
            }
            #inner-container {
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            }
            p {
                margin-top: 0px;
            }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner-container">
        <p>Body Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```